# Parsing without duplicates using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

UPDATE

I have an xml that I want to filter on strings that contain 'TYPE' and also not add if the string right after 'TYPE' is a duplicate. I have this piece of my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<INSERT>
<GROUP>,TEST,015182053980,TYPE,Car</GROUP>
<GROUP>,TEST,015182053980,DATE,2016</GROUP>
<GROUP>,ITEM,015182053997,ITEM,60200002,,STANDARD,061</GROUP>
<GROUP>,TEST,015182053997,TYPE,Car</GROUP>
<GROUP>,TEST,015182053997,DATE,2017</GROUP>
<GROUP>,TEST,015182054154,ITEM,60200002,,STANDARD,061</GROUP>
<GROUP>,TEST,015182054154,TYPE,Truck</GROUP>
<GROUP>,TEST,015182054154,DATE,2018</GROUP>
<GROUP>,TEST,015182054161,ITEM,60200002,,STANDARD,061</GROUP>
<GROUP>,TEST,015182054161,TYPE,Truck</GROUP>
<GROUP>,TEST,015182054161,DATE,2016</GROUP>
<GROUP>,TEST,015182054178,ITEM,60200002,,STANDARD,061</GROUP>
<GROUP>,TEST,015182054178,TYPE,Truck</GROUP>
<GROUP>,TEST,015182054178,DATE,2017</GROUP>
<GROUP>,TEST,015182054215,ITEM,60200002,,STANDARD,061</GROUP>
<GROUP>,TEST,015182054215,TYPE,Motorcycle</GROUP>
<GROUP>,TEST,015182054215,DATE,2018</GROUP>
<GROUP>,TEST,015182054222,ITEM,60200002,,STANDARD,061</GROUP>
<GROUP>,TEST,015182054222,TYPE,Motorcycle</GROUP>
<GROUP>,TEST,015182054222,DATE,2016</GROUP>
</INSERT>
```

And I want an xml that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Brand>
 <Vehicle>Car</Vehicle>
</Brand>
<Brand>
 <Vehicle>Truck</Vehicle>
</Brand>
<Brand>
 <Vehicle>Motorcycle</Vehicle>
</Brand>
```

Right now, my xsl looks like:

```
<xsl:template match= "GROUP">
<xsl:if test="contains(., 'TYPE')">
<TEST>
 <Brand>
 <Vehicle><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'TYPE,')"/></Vehicle>
 </Brand>
</TEST>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

My Current Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Brand>
 <Vehicle>Car</Vehicle>
</Brand>
<Brand>
<Brand>
 <Vehicle>Car</Vehicle>
</Brand>
<Brand>
 <Vehicle>Truck</Vehicle>
</Brand>
<Brand>
 <Brand>
 <Vehicle>Truck</Vehicle>
</Brand>
<Brand>
 <Brand>
 <Vehicle>Truck</Vehicle>
</Brand>
<Brand>
 <Vehicle>Motorcycle</Vehicle>
</Brand>
<Brand>
 <Vehicle>Motorcycle</Vehicle>
</Brand>
```

Right now, I get all lines with 'TYPE' and I am not sure how to update this

Comment: The input is not valid XML as it has multiple root elements, and there is no `<INSERT>` tag in the input for the template to match. Please provide complete, consistent input, output and XSLT.

Comment: Can you also say whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 here? Thank you.

Comment: And if you're using XSLT 1.0, which processor is it?

Comment: Oh, thats my bad.  It is XSLT 2.0. The root is INSERT, I just clipped a piece of the full XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using XSLT 2.0, you can use `xsl:for-each-group` here.

Try this XSTL

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="INSERT">
    <Brands>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="GROUP[contains(., ',TYPE,')]" group-by="substring-after(., ',TYPE,')">
        <Brand>
          <Vehicle>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
          </Vehicle>
        </Brand>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Brands>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: By any chance, can you show how this would look in xslt 1.0.  I was just curious between the two...

Comment: You need to use a technique called "Muenchian Grouping" in XSLT. See http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html